# Logging my rails application's users into facebook through iframe display option hangs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

This code does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({appId: "<%= FACEBOOK_CONFIG['application_id'] %>", status: true, cookie: true,
                     xfbml: true});



                FB.ui(
                   {
                     method: 'oauth',
                    client_id: "<%= FACEBOOK_CONFIG['application_id'] %>",
                    scope: "<%= FACEBOOK_CONFIG['permissions'] %>",
                    state: "<%= secure_hash(FACEBOOK_CONFIG['secret_phrase']) %>"

                   },
                   function(response) {
                     if (response && response.post_id) {
                       alert('Post was published.');
                     } else {
                       alert('Post was not published.');
                     }
                   }
                     );
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You've done the FB.init({appId: ..., xfbml: true}); bit first right?

I think the method you want to call is {method: 'oauth'} like:

```
        FB.ui({ method: 'oauth',
                client_id: <%= FACEBOOK_CONFIG['application_id'] %>,
                scope: '<%= FACEBOOK_CONFIG['permissions'] %>',
                state: '<%= secure_hash(FACEBOOK_CONFIG['secret_phrase']) %>'
              },
              function (response) {
                if (response && response.post_id) {
                  alert('success');
                } else {
                  alert('failure');
                }
              }
        );
```

Although, to just do a login it's easier to call:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.session) { alert('success'); }
      else { alert('nope'); }
});
```

Comment: I updated my code and show what I am running above and am still running into problems. Any ideas?

Comment: This solution doesn't work because FB.getLoginStatus doesn't let you display the login dialog in an iframe. Also, my code above does not work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: So it looks like you can't log a user into a 3rd-party web app using an iframe. I got this error: API Error Code: 1
API Error Description: An unknown error occurred
Error Message: Unsupported display: 'iframe'. Supported displays: popup, page, wap, touch when I submitted the following request via my browser to test the api: http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?scope=email,user_birthday,publish_stream&client_id=MY_APP_ID&display=iframe&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/&response_type=token